# Does risk aversion cause diminishing marginal utility, or vice versa?

Tags: economics, social-choice-theory

Let $A$ be the set of possible states of the world, or possible preferences a person could have. Let $G(A)$ be the set of "gambles" or "lotteries", i.e. the set of probability distributions over $A$. Then each person would have a preferred ordering of the states in $A$, as well as a preferred ordering of the lotteries in $G(A)$. The von Neumann-Morgenstern theorem states that, assuming your preference ordering over $G(A)$ obeys certain rationality axioms, your preferences can be represented by a utility function $u: A → ℝ$. (This function is unique up to multiplication of scalars and addition of constants.) That means that for any two lotteries $L_1$ and $L_2$ in $G(A)$, you prefer $L_1$ to $L_2$ if and only if the expected value of $u$ under $L_1$ is greater than the expected value of $u$ under $L_2$. In other words, you maximize the expected value of the utility function.

Now just because you maximize the expected value of your utility function does not mean that you maximize the expected value of actual things like money. After all, people are often risk averse; they say "a bird in the hand is worth two in the bush". Risk aversion means that you value a gamble less than expected value of the money you'll gain. If we express this notion in terms of the von Neumann-Morgenstern utility function, we get the following result: a person is risk averse if and only if their utility function is a concave function of your money, i.e. the extent to which you're risk averse is the same as the extent to which you have a diminishing marginal utility of money. (See page 13 of [this PDF](http://www.stanford.edu/~jdlevin/Econ%20202/Uncertainty.pdf).)

My question is, which direction does the causation run? Do the values of the von Neumann-Morgenstern utility function reflect the intensity of your preferences, and is risk aversion due to discounting the preferences of future selves who are well-off compared to the preferences of future versions of yourself who are poorer and thus value money more (as Brad Delong suggests [here](http://delong.typepad.com/sdj/2011/08/1049-million.html))? Or does the causation run the other way: does your tolerance for risk determine the shape of your utility function, so that the von Neumann-Morgenstern utility function tells you nothing about the relative intensity of your preferences?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You in Advance.

Comment: I don't think your question is really mathematical in nature.

Comment: @TBrendle There's no economics stackexchange site, so Math.SE was the closest thing I found.  The question is somewhat mathematical, since as Michael mentioned in his answer, the theorem being discussed is basically Jensen's inequality, although you're right that what I'm fundamentally asking is an economic question.

Answer (score 2):

They are equivalent. Let $\mathcal{G}$ be Borel probability measures on $\mathbb{R}$ with finite first moment (i.e. lotteries). Then a measurable function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}\;$ (i.e. vNM utility) satisfies

$$
\int f(x) d\mu \leq f (\int x d \mu) \; \; \forall \mu \in \mathcal{G} 
$$

if and only if $f$ is concave. The "only if" part is trivial; "if" is Jensen's inequality.

Comment: I'm aware that they're equivalent, I stated that in my question.  The vNM utility function being concave is equivalent to the utility of a lottery being less than the expected value of the money you'll gain.  But that doesn't answer the question of which direction the causality runs.   Is risk aversion a result of diminishing marginal utility, or does the von Neumann-Morgenstern utility function not reflect intensity of preferences at all, but rather reflect your appetite for your risk?

Comment: Being a bachelor and being unmarried are equivalent. In which way does the causation run: is the bachelor unmarried because he is a bachelor, or is he a bachelor because he is unmarried? The question doesn't make sense: they are *equivalent*.

Comment: @Nameless Yes, having a vNM utility function which is concave and valuing a lottery less than its expected value are equivalent.  But my fundamental question is, does the vNM utility function reflect intensity of preferences, or does it not reflect intensity of preferences but instead reflect attitudes toward risk which are independent of your preferences concerning states of the world?